# HTTPS WCF Service on Windows Phone 8.0 : Cannot authenticate

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

i'm experiencing problems on my WP8.0 app, I want to access a HTTPS WCF service from it with BASIC authentication.

Everything is **already** working on a C# console app which uses .NET framework 4.5

**WORKING CONSOLE APP CODE :**

App.config :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpsBinding>
                <binding name="WS_CubicusMobileSOAPBinding">
                  <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="xxxxxx.xx.xx" />
                  </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpsBinding >

      </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://xxx.xxx.xx/xxx/awws/xxxxx.awws"
                binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS_CubicusMobileSOAPBinding"
                contract="ServiceReference1.WS_CubicusMobileSOAPPortType"
                name="WS_CubicusMobileSOAPPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**And this C# code :**

```cs
ServiceReference1.WS_CubicusMobileSOAPPortTypeClient proxy = new WS_CubicusMobileSOAPPortTypeClient();
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxxxx";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxxx";
var e = proxy2.ConnexionTestWP(anObject);
```

**NOT WORKING WP8.0 CODE :**

**ServiceReferences.ClientConfig :**

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WS_CubicusMobileSOAPBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx/xxxxx/awws/xxxxx.awws"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS_CubicusMobileSOAPBinding"
        contract="ServiceReference1.WS_CubicusMobileSOAPPortType" name="WS_CubicusMobileSOAPPort" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

The C# code is exactly the same than the console app one (except it's Async).

I receive a CommunicationException saying "Additional information: The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

The only thing Fiddler sees : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzYhf.png

I heard that Silverlight clients needs crossdomain.xml on client side to work, so I included this file on the server root. Still not working...

I feel like I tried every binding (like custombinding), every c# code (like adding the Authorization header inside the WCF request manually), every kind of configuration etc... Nothing is working.

Please help me out i'm desperate !

Answer (score 0):

You're using `basicHttpBinding` in Windows Phone but `basicHttpsBinding` in console app. Have you turned off `http` on the server?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. basicHttpsBinding doesn't exist on the silverlight .NET subnet (WP8.0 in that case). Anyway, according to MSDN, basicHttpBinding can also handle HTTPS.